# how to add 'node-red-node-pi-sense-hat' in Node-Red?

Tags: node-red

I've been trying to use sense hat on my Windows 10 computer. But when I try to install it on node red I get the error all the time.

[image]

there are some explanations on the error log but I don't really understand how to fix the problem with that information.

Comment: What error logs showing up. You need to post more relevant data if you wanna help from somebody.

Comment: Edit the question to include the text of the log, use the tool bar to format it properly not link to an offsite resource which will probably disappear after some time and is full of random adverts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not install the `node-red-pi-sense-hat` node on Windows 10. It requires the actual hardware attached to the a Raspberry Pi to work (And if I'm not mistaken it will also only work on Linux). It also requires a number of pre-requists to be installed first as described in the README.md

If you can install the [Sense Hat Simulator](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-pi-sense-hat-simulator) node which provides the same input/output interface and a webpage with which to inject events and to see the output from the LEDs.